# When is explicit recursion necessary?

Tags: haskell, recursion, idioms

In Haskell, it is idiomatic to write as much of your code in higher-order functions like folds, maps, and unfolds as possible. So what kinds of code can't be written with those higher-order functions? When is explicit recursion necessary?

Comment: Are you asking when recursion is *necessary* or when it's *idiomatic*? Your title says the first; your last sentence says the second.

Comment: Good point. I was kind of wondering both, but I'll limit it to one question: When is explicit recursion actually necessary? I'll edit the question.

Comment: Higher order functions like `map` and `fold` are implemented with recursion. If you are using them, semantically, you are using recursion. Syntactically, you never have to use recursion, except once - to define the "canonical recursive function" - `fix f = let x = f x in x`.

Comment: But `fix` is cheating -- an honest programmer would say a function that uses `fix` is recursive.  There is a rich theory of the schemes below `fix`; see [Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes and Barbed Wire](http://wwwhome.ewi.utwente.nl/~fokkinga/mmf91m.pdf) for a famous treatment.

Comment: @user2407038 From a Haskellian perspective, computational theory only goes so far—polymorphic recursion is not likely to do so well with `fix`.

Comment: You can get polymorphic recursion with `fix`, but you need a newtype wrapper to tell Haskell precisely where you want to instantiate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's assume we have a language without recursion or anything like it. This means no looping structures either. It also means we have (non-recursive) types as well so that we can't form a Y-combinator and escape. In this language, we are truly weak, separated from so many of our tools.

But we can ask a very good question about this language. Namely, what is the smallest thing we must give it in order for it to become just as powerful as a language with no such restrictions?

It turns out there are two answers.

1. We can introduce recursive binders, like a `let rec` command or something like Haskell's `let` which is always `let rec`. In other words, a structure which lets us define `let x = e in b` such that if `x` is free in `e` then it is computed as a fixed point on the equation `x = e`.
2. We can introduce the function `fix :: (a -> a) -> a` such that `fix f` reduces in one step to `f (fix f)`.

It should be clear from the above presentation that `fix` can be implemented using recursive binders. What's a little less clear is that recursive binders can be implemented from non-recursive ones using fix, but here we are:

```
let x = fix $ \this -> e
```

The value `this` refers to the whole expression which ends up bound as `x` which is just what we want.

---

So why did I go out of my way to say all of the above?

Essentially, I'd like to argue that it's not possible to say that recursion is necessarily implemented via HOF combinators like `map` so long as you're willing to consider `fix` on that list. I'd also like to argue that any recursion implemented by combinators in that set can be done "explicitly" using recursive binders. They're equally powerful.

The interesting part comes in when you consider HOF combinators like `foldr`/`unfoldr` by themselves. These are technically somewhat *weaker* than `fix`/recursive binders. The advantage is that if you build a programming language off only a select set of `foldr`/`unfoldr`-like principles then you can get a very rich, sub-Turing complete language which can be *total* or guaranteed to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of people find recursive data definitions easier to read than Mu/Fix/Nu types.  It's not strictly necessary, but very useful there.

Similarly, you'll write the Foldable/Unfoldabe instances for such a data type by using recursion, but once those are provided, explicit recursion is not required going forward.